# Where are there no version numbers in these dependencies?

Tags: maven, dependency-properties

I am reading a POM.xml file and wonder why there are no version numbers for all these dependencies?

Typically, when specifying a dependency, a version number should be included. Right? Or version is totally optional?

```
<dependencies>

    <!-- First declare the APIs we depend on and need for compilation. All 
        of them are provided by JBoss AS 7 -->

    <!-- Import the CDI API, we use provided scope as the API is included in 
        JBoss AS 7 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.enterprise</groupId>
        <artifactId>cdi-api</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Import the Common Annotations API (JSR-250), we use provided scope 
        as the API is included in JBoss AS 7 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.annotation</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-annotations-api_1.1_spec</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Import the JAX-RS API, we use provided scope as the API is included 
        in JBoss AS 7 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.ws.rs</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-jaxrs-api_1.1_spec</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Import the JPA API, we use provided scope as the API is included in 
        JBoss AS 7 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Import the EJB API, we use provided scope as the API is included in 
        JBoss AS 7 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.ejb</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-ejb-api_3.1_spec</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- JSR-303 (Bean Validation) Implementation -->
    <!-- Provides portable constraints such as @Email -->
    <!-- Hibernate Validator is shipped in JBoss AS 7 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Import the JSF API, we use provided scope as the API is included in 
        JBoss AS 7 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Now we declare any tools needed -->

    <!-- Annotation processor to generate the JPA 2.0 metamodel classes for 
        typesafe criteria queries -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpamodelgen</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Annotation processor that raising compilation errors whenever constraint 
        annotations are incorrectly used. -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator-annotation-processor</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Needed for running tests (you may also use TestNG) -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Optional, but highly recommended -->
    <!-- Arquillian allows you to test enterprise code such as EJBs and Transactional(JTA) 
        JPA from JUnit/TestNG -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>arquillian-junit-container</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.protocol</groupId>
        <artifactId>arquillian-protocol-servlet</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

Answer (score 1):

The version number is not optional, but it's not mandatory that you have to specify the version numbers with the `dependencies/dependency` tag itself.

Consider an  multi-module application where few of your modules are using a common logging framework. How difficult it would be to declare the logging framework dependency version in each module which uses it and then update it everywhere when you want to upgrade to the next version of the logging framework? If not done properly you might end up with different versions of the logging framework in different interdependent modules. It would be tedious and that's the reason why Maven has the concept of a centralized dependency Management.

With Maven,you can  manage your dependency version numbers within the `<dependencyManagement/>` section(this would be declared in the parent pom in my use case above).

i.e Somewhere within you code base you should probably find  the dependency version information(something like the below)

```
<dependencyManagement>
  <!-- other dependencies -->
  <dependency>
    <groupId>javax.enterprise</groupId>
    <artifactId>cdi-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.1</scope>
   </dependency>
  <!-- other dependencies -->
</dependencyManagement>
```

Read more from the [official Maven documentation](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a dependencyManagement section, but it's for none of them. ${version.jboss.bom} is provided in one property defined earlier, but it's not for any of these. I can't find other dependency management. It's a simple demo and there is only one POM.

```
....
<version.jboss.bom>1.0.4.Final-redhat-4</version.jboss.bom>
....


<dependencyManagement> 
    <dependencies>
        <!-- JBoss distributes a complete set of Java EE 6 APIs including a Bill 
            of Materials (BOM). A BOM specifies the versions of a "stack" (or a collection) 
            of artifacts. We use this here so that we always get the correct versions 
            of artifacts. Here we use the jboss-javaee-6.0-with-tools stack (you can 
            read this as the JBoss stack of the Java EE 6 APIs, with some extras tools 
            for your project, such as Arquillian for testing) and the jboss-javaee-6.0-with-hibernate 
            stack you can read this as the JBoss stack of the Java EE 6 APIs, with extras 
            from the Hibernate family of projects) -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.bom</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-javaee-6.0-with-tools</artifactId>
            <version>${version.jboss.bom}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.bom</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-javaee-6.0-with-hibernate</artifactId>
            <version>${version.jboss.bom}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```